# element.click in directive unit test not assigning value to variables

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am testing the directive below that uses an isolated scope. I know the triggerHandler is working but for some reason I keep getting the error

> Expected undefined to equal 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12345?s=40&d=identicon'.

Directive:

```
angular.module('pb.webSites.directives')
    .directive('pbOrganizationImagePicker', [ function () {

        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: '<img data-ng-src="{{ imageSource }}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" alt="Image Picker" class="img-rounded" />',
            scope: {
                fileId: '=pbFileId',
                defaultSrc: '@pbDefaultSrc',
                width: '@pbWidth',
                height: '@pbHeight'
            },
            controller: 'pbOrganizationImagePickerController',

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('defaultSrc', function (value) {
                    if (value !== undefined) {
                        scope.imageSource = value;
                    }
                });

                element.on('click', function () {
                    scope.pickImage().then(function (image) {
                        scope.imageSource = image.storageUrl;
                        scope.fileId = image.fileId;
                    }, function () {
                        console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Tests:

```
describe('pbOrganizationImagePicker', function () {

    beforeEach(module('pb.webSites.controllers'));
    beforeEach(module('pb.webSites.directives'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.bootstrap'));

    var compile;
    var scope;
    var mockModal = {};
    var image;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        compile = $compile
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));


    beforeEach(inject(function ($q, $injector) {

        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/app/webSites/directives/OrganizationImagePicker.html').respond(200, '');

        scopeObject = {
            profileImageUrl: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12345?s=40&d=identicon',
            profileImageId: 54634
        };

        scope.webSite = {
            profileImageId: 6436
        };

        scope.pickImage = function () {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            defer.resolve(scopeObject);
            return defer.promise;
        };

    }));

describe('element.click()', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            var html = angular.element('<pb-organization-image-picker data-pb-default-src="{{ webSite.profileImageUrl || \'/content/img/placeholder-lg.jpg\' }}" data-pb-file-id="webSite.profileImageId" data-pb-width="200"></pb-organization-image-picker>');
            element = compile(html)(scope);
            element.triggerHandler('click');
        });

        it('should assign value to scope variables', function () {
            scope.pickImage();
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.imageSource).toEqual(scopeObject.profileImageUrl);
            expect(scope.fileId).toEqual(scopeObject.profileImageId);
        });

    });
```

});

I have also tried changing the test to the following since Im pretty sure in the test above I am faking the test a bit. However here I get pickImage() was never called. Even if you dont see the problem which method do you think is better for testing?

```
describe('element.click()', function () {


        it('should assign value to scope variables', function () {
            element = compile(html)(scope);
            spyOn(scope, 'pickImage');
            element.triggerHandler('click');
            scope.$apply();
            //scope.pickImage();
            expect(scope.pickImage).toHaveBeenCalled();
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.imageSource).toEqual(scopeObject.profileImageUrl);
            expect(scope.fileId).toEqual(scopeObject.profileImageId);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element.on('click', function () {
    scope.$apply(function() {
       scope.pickImage().then(function (image) {
           scope.imageSource = image.storageUrl;
           scope.fileId = image.fileId;
       }, function () {
           console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
       });
    });
});
```

Wrap the code in your click handler in an $apply.

I suspect the real problem is that your directive uses an isolate scope, so it actually won't have a "pickImage()" method and when you assign imageSource and fileId, you are putting them on the directive scope, and not the scope that your test is trying to validate (the parent scope).

Your test assigns pickImage() and webSite to the scope of your test element.  Since you use an isolated scope, your directive won't have access to these methods and properties.  You should probably move these to a service and inject them into the directive.

It's not "correct", but to test the theory you can change your directive to:

```
element.on('click', function () {
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent.pickImage().then(function (image) {
            scope.$parent.imageSource = image.storageUrl;
            scope.$parent.fileId = image.fileId;
        }, function () {
            console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    });
});
```

This IS NOT something you want in production code, but I'm just trying to demonstrate how the different scopes are related to each other.

Comment: It still needs to be there (for your in the wild code).  The test might work because you call scope.digest() manually in the test.

Comment: That really helped clarify the scope problems I have been having. Thanks. Keeping that in mind I am looking for changes on the element.isolateScope() now. It is still not showing the new values from having called the click but I think im closer. I would use your suggestion of using a service but at this point its not my code base to change. If I keep having trouble with this one I will bring it up and try to make the changes you suggested. Thanks again!

Comment: It probably won't because pickImage is undefined in the directive, so it's probably just throwing an exception when you call it.  I made a small change to the call (so that it calls $parent.pickImage().  I can't emphasize enough, though, that while it should make your test work, it's not the way to really fix the issue - hopefully just clarify the relationship between the two scopes.